# Windows 10 shutdown delayed

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

The issue only started occurring recently, although no significant changes were made to the system.
Upon selecting the shutdown option in Start, Windows present the normal shutdown screen which is displayed for about the same as a normal shutdown sequence. Video signal goes out, but the HDD, MB and case fans keep going for another minute-3 min.
No abnormal activity in the log, although the system log, interestingly, shows the system entering sleep state ("Reason: Application API"), and then exiting that state, at the same time as the shutdown was initiated.
Any idea what that might be caused by?

Comment: I can't tell you why, but I noticed this too. I think this could be a bug no one noticed and reported to MS. Probably has something to do with the fact that windows goes to standby rather than actually turning off.

Comment: @LPChip I figure the Sleep thing might be due to Fast Boot, although it didn't previously slow down shutdowns

Comment: Yeah, indeed. But it did a shutdown faster in the past if my memory serves me correctly.

Comment: Certainly. Interestingly, the last update I had installed was NET from 22.06, so it wasn't update-induced. I had switched Power from Balanced to MaxPerf, wondering if that might've affected it. Anyway, the questions is now answered

Answer (score 0):

Disabling hibernation fixed the slow shutdowns, making them essentially instant and in sync with the shutdown screen. Enabling it back once again slows down shutdown (albeit not as dramatically as previously?).
Event log displays shut down correctly (as a shutdown) when disabling hibernation, and reverts back to "sleep-wake" log entries with it enabled.
I'll monitor performance but will leave it enabled for now just for the faster startups.

*Still, why is it so convoluted and mislabeled even in the event log is beyond me. A user would expect the machine to shutdown when the shutdown options is chosen. Gotta love modern Win*

Comment: As far as I know, this is since the Creators Update. And by disabling hibernation, you essentially disable fast startup too. So booting up takes longer now, depending on your system specs.

Comment: @LPChip well, I haven't received CU yet and am on 1607. I haven't noticed any serious startup lag after disabling hibernation but enabled it anyway